# Bug when drawing a QImage on a widget with PIL and PyQt

Tags: python, image, qt, pyqt, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a small graphic application, and I need to
construct some image using PIL that I show in a widget.
The image is correctly constructed (I can check with im.show()),
I can convert it to a QImage, that I can save normally to disk
(using QImage.save), but if I try to draw it directly on my
QWidget, it only show a white square.

Here I commented out the code that is not working (converting the
Image into QImage then QPixmap result in a white square), and I
made a dirty hack to save the image to a temporary file and load it directly
in a QPixmap, which work but is not what I want to  do

https://gist.github.com/f6d479f286ad75bf72b7

Someone has an idea?

If it can help, when I try to save my QImage in a BMP file, I can access its content, but if I try to save it to a PNG it is completely  white

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem, then noticed, that ImageQt objects are not QImages, but can simply be casted to those

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#written by Sebastian Stetter in 2010


import sys
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *



def PILimageToQImage(pilimage):
    """converts a PIL image to QImage"""
    imageq = ImageQt(pilimage) #convert PIL image to a PIL.ImageQt object
    qimage = QImage(imageq) #cast PIL.ImageQt object to QImage object -that´s the trick!!!
    return qimage




if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Testcode
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    pim = Image.open(unicode(QFileDialog().getOpenFileName()))
    pim.show() #show pil image

    qim = PILimageToQImage(pim)
    pm = QPixmap(qim)
    lbl = QLabel()
    lbl.setPixmap(pm)
    lbl.show() #show label with qim image

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same thing with Qt-3 using [QImage.loadFromData()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimage.html#loadFromData). I imagine it still works in Qt-4:

```
self.image = QImage()
if self.image.loadFromData(image_data,"PNG"):
    # image loaded successfully
```

Comment: Yeah, but my program should not use hacks like this, since PIL ImageQt.ImageQt correctly(?) converts the image to a QImage, I should be able to display it directly! I don't know why it shows
as a white rect..

Comment: `loadFromData` returns a bool indicating success or failure and allows you to specify the image format.  Thus, it gives you further insight into why it's failing. If the image is correctly being loaded, there is no valid reason it should display correctly in one case but not in another. Ideally `ImageQt` will give you a valid `QImage`.