# Pillow (PIL) to QImage conversion -> python.exe has stopped working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, python-imaging-library

I want to load an Image with PIL, apply some filtering and then display the image on a GUI.

I have written a little sample application:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PIL import Image, ImageQt

class TwoDToThreeD(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.btnOpen = self.createButton("Open File", self.open)

        layout.addWidget(self.btnOpen, 4, 0)

        self.imageLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)
        self.imageLabel.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)

        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel, 0, 2, 4, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 10)
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 20)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def createButton(self, text, member):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton(text)
        button.clicked.connect(member)
        return button


    def open(self):
        fileName = (QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", QtCore.QDir.currentPath()))
        if fileName:
            print (fileName)
            self.imgPil = Image.open(str(fileName))

            # print (PIL.VERSION)

            print (self.imgPil.format, self.imgPil.size, self.imgPil.mode)
            # imgPil.show()
            img_tmp = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.imgPil)

            image = QtGui.QImage(img_tmp)

            if image.isNull():
                QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Image Viewer", "Cannot load %s." % fileName)
                return

            self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = TwoDToThreeD()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Loading a *.png works fine. But when I try to load a *.jpg python just crashes:

```
python.exe has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is
available.
```

I am on Windows 8.1 64Bit and tried the very same source with python 2.7 64bit, python 2.7 32bit and python 3.4 64bit.

With all 3 versions I get the same result.

Has anybody experienced similar problems or knows a solution?
I can't even debug the code, since it runs til the "end" and then crashes :(

Comment: Can you work out which line is doing the crashing (with some sleeps or something)? As a guess you could try replacing `fromImage` with `convertFromImage`.

Comment: I can replicate on linux , I can open pics once they are roughly < 30kb anything larger gives an exit 139 which is a segmentation fault as far as I know.

Comment: I have the problem with jpegs too, pngs work fine. I just want to display an PIL image in QtControl efficiently. If you know another solution, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Maecky, actually same for png's also, at least for me. Does opening a very small jpeg work for you?

Comment: I just tested it, opening a small jpep works, but if I resize the window, python crashes again. Am I doing something wrong? I found the PIL to PyQt conversion here on stackoverflow makred as correct answer. Other samples on the web suggest the same procedure... Is there an alternatvie, to display an Image from PIL in PyQt (I would prefer, that i can update the Image in realtime, e.g. I have implement a contrast slider and when the user drags the slider, he can see the update in image in 'realtime')

Comment: does  `self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(fileName))` work?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, yes this works - even with large jpegs and resizing of the windows is also possible. But with this "solution" I can't modify the image with PIL...

Comment: what does the `img_tmp = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.imgPil)` do?

Comment: According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041728/bug-when-drawing-a-qimage-on-a-widget-with-pil-and-pyqt a cast is needed. If I omit the cast, image.isNull() is true...

Comment: @Maecky, added an answer let me know if it works, based on example from here https://github.com/shuge/Qt-Python-Binding-Examples/blob/master/image/display_img/pil_to_qpixmap.py

Answer (score 2):

In `PyQt5` and Python 3.8 this no longer works. I would write the `pil2pixmap` function as follows.

```
import io
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PIL import Image


def pil2pixmap(image):
    bytes_img = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(bytes_img, format='JPEG')

    qimg = QImage()
    qimg.loadFromData(bytes_img.getvalue())

    return QPixmap.fromImage(qimg)
```

where the argument `image` is for example `image = Image.open('path_to_a_picture')`

*Note: to use the function a QGuiApplication must run*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example from [github](https://github.com/shuge/Qt-Python-Binding-Examples/blob/master/image/display_img/pil_to_qpixmap.py)

```
def pil2pixmap(self,im):
        if im.mode == "RGB":
            pass
        elif im.mode == "L":
            im = im.convert("RGBA")
        data = im.convert("RGBA").tostring("raw", "RGBA")
        qim = QtGui.QImage(data, im.size[0], im.size[1], QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        return pixmap
    def open(self):
        fileName = (QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", QtCore.QDir.currentPath()))
        if fileName:
            imgPil = Image.open(str(fileName))
            # do your work then convert
            self.imageLabel.setPixmap(self.pil2pixmap(imgPil))
```