# how to avoid (PIL) imageQt's bizarre behaviour?

Tags: python, pyqt, python-imaging-library, qimage

I do image mosaicking with PIL and want to view the result with *QGraphicsView*. To do so, I have subclassed [*QtImageViewer*](https://github.com/marcel-goldschen-ohm/PyQtImageViewer/blob/master/QtImageViewer.py). The relevant method there is

```
def setImage(self, image):
    """ Set the scene's current image pixmap to the input QImage or QPixmap.
    Raises a RuntimeError if the input image has type other than QImage or QPixmap.
    :type image: QImage | QPixmap
    """
#    image.save("r:/test.png")
    if isinstance(image, QPixmap):
        pixmap = image
    elif isinstance(image, QImage):
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("ImageViewer.setImage: Argument must be a QImage or QPixmap.")

    if self.hasImage():
        self._pixmapHandle.setPixmap(pixmap)
    else:
        self._pixmapHandle = self.scene.addPixmap(pixmap)
    self.setSceneRect(QRectF(pixmap.rect()))  # Set scene size to image size.
    self.updateViewer()
```

The call I make from its subclass reads:

```
    def redraw(self):
        img = Image.new("RGB", (self.width(), self.height()), "gray")
        if self._source is not None:
            self._source.paintMap(img)
        img.save("r:/debug.png")
#         self.setImage(QImage("r:\debug.png"))
        self.setImage(ImageQt(img))
```

In both snippets there are lines of test code, saving the image content to temporary files. When I save the PIL image (*img.save("r:/debug.png")*) and create a *QImage* from that file (*self.setImage(QImage("r:\debug.png"))*) then the image is displayed correctly.

**problem**

desired result:
[image]

result I get with normal run:
[image]

Now there are three scenarios that can be observed:

1. just run the code (without the test code): a graphic is shown, but apparently it is a block of random memory, though seemingly always the same.
2. debug the code, stop it in *setImage*(), and save the incoming image: both the saved file and the image as displayed are correct.
3. debug or run with the line *image.save("r:/test.png")* uncommented: then python crashes.

So, I think something is rotten in *ImageQt*, that eventually may be corrected. The odd behaviour reminds of the issue [Nick Morgan discusses](http://skilldrick.co.uk/2010/03/pyqt-pil-and-windows/), but just wrapping *imageQt* within another *QImage* does not change the case to its better. And oh, yes, I am running under Windows.

Further: there is no connection whatsoever with [PIL Image to QPixmap conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697559/pil-image-to-qpixmap-conversion-issue)  for that issue is about the order of colour chanels and has nothing to do with spurious memory pointers in imageQt.

**questions**

- is an alternative conversion method available (save and read as work-around?) ?
- can imageQt be nudged to behave like it should (or am I doing something wrong myself)?

Comment: I do not understand your question, why do you need to save the file to just read it back ?, that can bring several inconveniences in the long term because many times you do not want to save to the hard drive for various reasons. Do you have a problem converting a PIL image to QImage? What problem does ImageQt have? provide a [mcve]

Comment: As stated above, that part is test code. I explicitly mention it here to show that the image it self is good and can be shown correctly. It should be unnecessary to save/read the image and thus slow down the program, but I disagree that in itself it is a bad idea, provided it is done in a proper temp folder.

Comment: I understand that point, but still 1) What is your problem? You do not explain it clearly, it seems that you assume that we know your problem, 2) you must provide an MCVE

Comment: It baffles me how you can mark this as a duplicate if you don't even understand the question. Your nearly completely mistaken here.

Comment: Because your answer is equivalent to saying "Use the other answer", I also understood your question when you did your last edition (the images) but I saw the answer that points to another answer that is equivalent to a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Padraic Cunningham** addressed the issue of crashing python in [Pillow (PIL) to QImage conversion -> python.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086613/pillow-pil-to-qimage-conversion-python-exe-has-stopped-working) and offered a work-around. However, in his example code the colour bands get mixed up. That issue is answered by **Jordan** in [pil-image to qpixmap conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697559/pil-image-to-qpixmap-conversion-issue). So finally, this adaptation solves my issue:

```
def redraw(self):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (self.width(), self.height()), "gray")
    if self._source is not None:
        self._source.paintMap(img)
    data = img.convert("RGB").tostring("raw", "RGB")
    qimg = QImage(data, img.size[0], img.size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)
    self.setImage(qimg)
```