# How to convert an image with PILLOW temporarily?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I know that PILLOW can convert an image from say jpg to png using the save method but is there a way to convert the image to another format and just keep it as an Image object without actually saving it as another file?

So I want to convert a user supplied image to common format for working with in the program because certain tools I am using only support png.

Comment: You cannot store an image in a different temporarily. You have to store it in a separate format, then refer to the new location for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

`jpg` and `png` are just compression techniques for saving an image to a file. An image as an object, is just an array of RGB(or any other colorspace/format used by the library which you used to read the file) values of all the pixels.

So technically, you can use the image object as the common format for working with other tools. But you need to keep in mind about the colorspace which is used by each library. Like, OpenCV considers an image object in BGR format, so you need to convert the image object to this format before you use it in OpenCV.

Comment: So how would I go about this? I also intend to display the image in my application in a qt graphic display which I've heard only accept pngs

Comment: I have no experience with qt but, after googling a bit, I found that it is indeed possible. Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28291210/4765857). Also, can you point me to the document which says _qt graphic display only accept pngs_?

Comment: Sorry I believe I got that from another Stack Overflow question and I don't remember which one. I managed to somewhat solve my problem for a few cases by testing the image mode for RGB and then converting to RGBA using Image.convert() it works in some cases, mostly jpgs. I know nothing about images really so I am going to say perhaps Qt Graphics displays require a certain colour space(?)

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirement is. If you're using only PIL and Qt, working with images between them should be easy. Yes, qt would require a certain colour space and format, but I can't comment about that since I have zero experience with Qt. Maybe check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041728/bug-when-drawing-a-qimage-on-a-widget-with-pil-and-pyqt) to get some more insight on Qt and PIL.